# Is there any way I can use value types in x:DataType?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, uwp

Given this `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="Color">
    ...
</DataTemplate>
```

I get the following error:

> The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('Color' is a non-nullable value type)

When you follow the error, it takes you to auto-generated code for that view which uses the `as` operator.

```
public void DataContextChangedHandler(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement sender, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DataContextChangedEventArgs args)
{
        global::Windows.UI.Color data = args.NewValue as global::Windows.UI.Color;
        if (args.NewValue != null && data == null)
        {
        throw new global::System.ArgumentException("Incorrect type passed into template. Based on the x:DataType global::Windows.UI.Color was expected.");
        }
        this.SetDataRoot(data);
        this.Update();
}
```

I know that `{x:Bind}` is new, but just in case, does anyone know how to configure it to allow value types, or at least use direct casting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same issue when binding the Windows Runtime Type like “Windows.UI.Color” in x:DateType.

The current workaround I used is wrapping a .NET Reference Type.

```
public class BindModel
{
    public Windows.UI.Color Color { get; set; }
}

<DataTemplate x:Key="test" x:DataType="local:BindModel">
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{x:Bind Color}"></SolidColorBrush>
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I was hoping I didn't have to do this, but I guess it's the only way. Thanks Jeffrey.

Answer (score 2):

@JeffreyChen's solution is absolutely correct and can be applied to any other value types. But in this particular instance, a reference typed `SolidColorBrush` which exposes a property of `Color` is something that the system has already built for you.

I'd suggest to change the `Color` property in your VM to `SolidColorBrush` because the only time you would need a `Color` in your xaml is when you want smooth `ColorAnimation` between two states. If this is the case you do -

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Vm.Brushes}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="SolidColorBrush">
            <TextBlock Text="Test">
                <TextBlock.Foreground>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{x:Bind Color}" />
                </TextBlock.Foreground>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Otherwise, you simply bind to XAML control's `Foreground`/`Background`/`BorderBrush` which is already a type of `Brush`.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Vm.Brushes}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="SolidColorBrush">
            <TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="{x:Bind}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: In this case, yes, the `SolidColorBrush` solves the problem. However, I am using `Color` as an example for a value type. I may have a value type coming from a portable library where the VMs live, or even use primitive types like `int[]` where `<DataTemplate x:DataType="x:Int32">`.